# SQL CASE in SELECT and WHERE for selecting rows

Tags: mysql, select, case

Is there any way to make this work:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN a=0 THEN "test1"
              WHEN a=1 THEN "test2"
         END AS a FROM table WHERE a LIKE "%test%"
```

So it should give me all rows where `a=0 or a=1`. The point is I need to search for these rows using string "test" .

Comment: Yes, just don't forget your `FROM` clause

Comment: FROM? So i schould put an secound query in this yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *,CASE WHEN a=0 THEN "test1"
                  WHEN a=1 THEN "test2"
             END AS b 
  FROM  TableA) TableB
WHERE b LIKE "%test%"
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7f01/1)

In case if you want to override field:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT CASE WHEN a=0 THEN "test1"
          WHEN a=1 THEN "test2"
     ELSE a
     END AS a 
  FROM  TableA) TableA
WHERE a LIKE "%test%"
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7f01/6)

Comment: That is what I need partly, but what if I want to do this inside one table and overriding the a?

Comment: Added select statement for overriding of field a of table. Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

give case in where like,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (CASE WHEN a=0 THEN "test1"
              WHEN a=1 THEN "test2"
         END)  LIKE "%test%"
```

Comment: this will give the same answer of the accepted , just try

Comment: indeed, sorry, I misunderstood what you wrote yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows where a=0 or a=1 you can use IN operator

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a IN (0,1)
```

But if you really want to use case you need FROM statement

Comment: Yes, I just forget it, but that is no the point. I wont search for the rows by using the string "test". That is why I use CASE

Answer (score 0):

There are two CASE statements, one for statements, second for expressions (what you need). You should do something like these -

```
SELECT CASE a WHEN 0 THEN 'test1' WHEN 1 THEN 'test2' END
```

Here it is a syntax - [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  ( CASE a
      WHEN 0 THEN "test1" 
      WHEN 1 THEN "test2" 
  END) as a_txt
FROM tableXY
```

Dunno what you want to do with the where "%test%"